# AngularJs calculation addition error

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 column in a table deduction,advance , total.
first two columns have their value from database and 3rd column is **sum of 1st two column**
**but** instead of summation i am getting result as **concatenated**.

```
<td data-title="'deduction>'">
   <span >{{payroll.deduction}}</span>
</td>
<td data-title="'advance''">
   <span >{{payroll.advance}}</span>
</td>
<td data-title="'total">
   <span >{{payroll.deduction+payroll.deduction}}</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables are being treated as strings.  Try using [`parseFloat()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) to convert them to numbers:

```
<td data-title="'deduction>'">
   <span >{{ payroll.deduction }}</span>
</td>
<td data-title="'advance''">
   <span >{{ payroll.advance }}</span>
</td>
<td data-title="'total">
   <span >{{ parseFloat(payroll.deduction) + parseFloat(payroll.advance) }}</span>
</td>
```

#### Edit:

[AngularJS expressions are not the exactly the same as JavaScript expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).  You will have to add a paseFloat to your controller in order to pull in the native `parseFloat` function:

```
function controller($scope)
{
    $scope.parseFloat = parseFloat;
}
```

Comment: is parseFloat() angularjs function?

Comment: No, it is native JavaScript.

Comment: That is a good point.  You will have to put the parseFloat() in your controller.  See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755558/how-to-sum-two-fields-in-angularjs-and-show-the-result-in-an-label.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parseFloat use parseInt function. One more thing i would like you to suggest to check in console whether its getting you string or not.