# get text box sum using angular js

Tags: angularjs

[image]i need to show total amount. first and second text box value sum should be display in total text box. have any way to do it.

```html
    <input type="text" ng-model="add.amount1"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="add.amount2"/>
  Total  <input type="text" ng-model={{add.amount1+add.amount2}}/>
```

Comment: Why not handle changeevent and calculate total?

Comment: <input type="text" ng-model={{add.amount1+add.amount2}}/>
this is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum two fields in AngularJS and show the result in an label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755558/how-to-sum-two-fields-in-angularjs-and-show-the-result-in-an-label)

Comment: my way is not working. can u help me to show total amount

Comment: Look at the potential duplicate I proposed and use `value` instead of `ng-model`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a ng-change on text boxes and call a function to calculate the sum.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.add = {};
$scope.add.amount1 = 0;
$scope.add.amount2 = 0;
$scope.calculateSum = function(){
  $scope.sum = parseInt($scope.add.amount1) + parseInt($scope.add.amount2);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
 <input type="text" ng-change="calculateSum()" ng-model="add.amount1"/>
<input type="text" ng-change="calculateSum()" ng-model="add.amount2"/>
Total  <input type="text" ng-model="sum"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Small issue. actually i have 5 textboxes. total amount  displayed when entered last textbox value. but total should be display and change when changing textbox values

Comment: then have ng-change only for the last text box value

Comment: check question. i added screen shot.if i enter measurement 05, total displayed

Comment: use ng-disabled and enabe it on ng-chage on textbox 5

Comment: sorry i did not get u. what for ng-disabled.

Comment: ok got your issue, initialize the scope variables to 0 as above sample

Comment: error  - Cannot set property 'measurement1' of undefined.
(according to your sample . measurement1 = amount1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166593/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-user1177842).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can also be considered

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "John Doe";
     $scope.add = {};
      $scope.add.amount1 = 1;
       $scope.add.amount2 = 2;
       $scope.sum = function(add) {
       
      
      return +add.amount1 + +add.amount2;
     }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app='myApp'>
<div ng-controller='myCtrl'>

<input type="text" ng-model="add.amount1"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="add.amount2"/>
  Total  <input type="text"  value="{{sum(add)}}" />
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```